# Is the usage 'formal leave of absence' correct? What does it imply? What could be possible inferences?

Tags: grammar, idioms, formality

Came across an email saying someone was on their 'formal leave of absence'

Is the phrase correctly used? That is, if it is correct in the first place.

What does it imply and what could be possible inferences? Thank you.

Comment: The phrase seems fairly clear: one is on a leave of absence from the position one otherwise occupies, which has been applied for and approved through some formal procedures. Which part of it is in need of being explained?

Comment: Perhaps "formal leave of absence" means "in writing", whereas "informal leave of absence" would be given verbally.

Comment: It implies authorised leave, as opposed to say,  phoning in sick.  The inferences would depend on the context, but it's not the typical terminology to describe holiday leave. It's the kind of wording used for disagreeable circumstances, but without more information, I'm only guessing.

Comment: If you want to ask about inferences that can be drawn and how it relates to modern-day workplaces, you're better asking in https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ This site is for questions about language and general usage points, not usage in a particular field. But wherever you post, it would be helpful if you would provide information about the country you're in and field of work, as inferences might vary between the US, UK, India, etc, and between public and private sector jobs.

Answer (score -1):

"leave of absence" is rarely used in current British and American English: simply "leave" is usually used because all leave involves an absence (from the workplace.)

In current English "leave" is usually not qualified, (John is on leave") although it can be qualified if the speaker wishes to be specific: study leave; sick leave; maternity/paternity leave; annual leave; disciplinary leave, etc.

Formal leave (of absence) is a type of leave that is specifically mentioned in the company's or organization's rules. "Formal", as an adjective, replaces the usual, more specific, qualifier and makes the reason for the leave vague/discreet.